# QGIS 2.01 - raster transparency not working properly

Tags: raster, transparency-opacity

[image: Trasnsparent raster image with underlying vector layer]I have loaded a color raster image (aerial orthoimagery) into a QGIS project.  The layer is visible but very transparent (in the enclosed image the vector polygons are below the imagery), but when I check Properties/Transparency the transparency is set to 0%.

The imagery is apparently color infrared. In QGIS 1.8 I simply went to the Color Map dialog and set the R-G-B color map to 4-1-2 respectively and the display was in perfect true color.  I cannot figure out how to do the same with 2.01. I have looked at the options under multiband and singleband pseudocolor and neither seems to give me the option to reset the color map as I was  able to do with 1.8. You can see that the image is displaying in true color, but highly transparent.  I did not change any color map settings.

When I view an older project that created with 1.8  with 2.01 imagery from this same data set displays perfectly, so it is not a problem with the source data. However, when I look at the Style settings for the older project with 2.01 I cannot find any differences between that project and the Style settings for the new project.

I don't konw if this is a color map issue or a trasparency issue, but I would simply like to get the image ot display properly.